# Java ActionListener class not writing to static variable

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, static-variables

to get to the point, i can't seam to write to a static double vareable, or JTextField from an external ActionListener class.
i am making an advanced calculator, and to make things easier, i am trying to create the GUI, imlementing its buttons, and other features, and i am trying to put the ActionListeners in anouther class. in eclipse, it says i need to have the vareables for the calculator static, but making them static, i can no longer write to them, and display answers.
this is the code i have:

```
public static JButton num0, num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9;
public static double tempNum1;
public static double tempNum2;
public static boolean pointOn = false;
public static int APC = 1;

public GUI(){
    GUINumListener numListener = new GUINumListener();

    num0.addActionListener(numListener);
    num1.addActionListener(numListener);
    num2.addActionListener(numListener);
    num3.addActionListener(numListener);
    num4.addActionListener(numListener);
    num5.addActionListener(numListener);
    num6.addActionListener(numListener);
    num7.addActionListener(numListener);
    num8.addActionListener(numListener);
    num9.addActionListener(numListener);
}
```

and in the GUINumListener class:

```
public class GUINumListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals(GUI.num0)){
            GUI.tempNum2 *= 10;
        }else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(GUI.num1)){
            if (GUI.pointOn = false){
                GUI.tempNum2 = (GUI.tempNum2 * 10) + 1;
            }else{
                GUI.tempNum2 = (GUI.tempNum2 * Math.pow(10, GUI.APC) + 1) / Math.pow(10, GUI.APC);
                GUI.APC++;
            }
            GUI.ansField.setText(Double.toString(GUI.tempNum2));
        }
    }
```

clicking a number in the program does not output it in the ansField field.
HELP!
thanks

Comment: Don't make them static. Eclipse is only complaining because the code doesn't compile, and is suggesting a solution to make it compile. But having code that compiles doesn't make it right and clean. Writable static variable are, 99.9% of times, a design smell. Oh, and fields should not be public either. Make them private or, at least, package-private.

Comment: I second all noted by @JBNizet above. And also learn about and use arrays or collections. If done properly, it can make your code both shorter and easier to debug and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use static fields, and also encapsulate them.

For `ActionListener` i always use inner private classes if the only scope is the outside class or `Anoymous Classes`.

Also it seems you have a collection of Button, you may consider grouping into collection.

Example (I comment in code):

```
private List<JButton> buttons;
private double tempNum1;
private double tempNum2;
private boolean pointOn = false;
private int APC = 1; 
//make them private why public and static? 


public GUI(){
    ActionListener numListener = new GUINumListener();

    //initiliatze buttons  

    int size=10;
    buttons= new ArrayList<>(size);

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
         JButton button = new JButton();
         button.addActionListener(numListener);
         buttons.add(button);             
    } 

}


private class GUINumListener implements ActionListener{
 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (e.getSource() == buttons.get(0)){ // actionCommand returns string you have to use getSource() or setting an actionCommand to the button and compare num0.getActionCommand()
             tempNum2 *= 10;
        }else if (e.getSource() == buttons.get(1)){
            if (!pointOn){ // u were assigning pointOn = false
                tempNum2 = (tempNum2 * 10) + 1;
            }else{
                tempNum2 = (tempNum2 * Math.pow(10, APC) + 1) / Math.pow(10, APC);
                APC++;
            }
            ansField.setText(Double.toString(tempNum2));
        }

}
```

Comment: i.e., make `GUINumListener` an inner class.

Comment: I figured you were getting there ;) This is the appropriate solution to the question.

Comment: Don't use set() to add() elements to a list. That will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `if` checks: `e.getActionCommand().equals(GUI.num0)`

`getActionCommand()` returns a `String` and `num0` is a `JButton`. So `equals` will always return `false` since they're not the same class type.

One way to solve this is to check the label of the button: `getActionCommand()`

So the `if` statement should be:

`e.getActionCommand().equals(GUI.num0.getActionCommand())`